# Email validation / remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a contact form in which missing fields and invalid fields are highlighted in red.  All is working well apart from the email validation field.  The issue I face is that when the user inputs an invalid email address into the email input field and submits the input field is highlighted red (perfect!), however when the user re-enters with a valid email address and submits the highlighted border remains.

```
function validateEmail(email) {
  var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
  return emailReg.test(email);
}


$("#contactForm").submit(function(event) {

  $("#email").removeClass("border-red");

  if (!validateEmail("#email")) {
    $("#email").addClass("border-red");
  }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the value of `#email` input to `validateEmail` function

```
if (!validateEmail($("#email").val()){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#contactForm").submit(function(event) 
 {
$("#email").removeClass("border-red"); 
if (!validateEmail($("#email").val()) 
{ 
$("#email").addClass("border-red"); 
} 
});
```